# Validation step before call function Javascript/jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, typescript

I have a wizard, (TypeScript, ASP.NET) with some steps.
Example

Step 1:

textBox input <---Name
textBox input <--- Age

button onClick="nextStep()"

When i click on the button i want do validate my input with jQuery Validation and call my fonction nextStep() if is ok.

Problem: is not in a form, nextStep call Ajax request.

Any fast solution?

Sorry im a beginner.

Comment: Research the build in aspnet Validation Controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving step ids to your `nextStep` methods

In your template:

```
<button onClick="nextStep(1)" />
```

In your typescript file:

```
nextStep(id: number): void {
   if (id == 1) {
     // do your validation, return false if not valid
   }

   // do your stuff if validation passed. Ex. ajax calls to server
}
```